# Do fruit trees attract wasps? What can I do other than cutting/removing the tree?

Tags: fruit-trees

I have a fruit tree in my garden. I don't exactly know what tree it is but it is likely a cheery apple tree or similar to that. The size of the fruits is similar to a small plum. They are mostly green but could be yellow when ripe or with a little hint of red. In the summer, the ripe fruits fall from the tree into the garden and starting to rot. My questions are:
1) is this likely to attract wasps?
2) is this likely to attract wasps to nest in the tree?
3) What measures can i take to mitigate the risks of wasps other than cutting back the tree which I have done last year, but i can't afford to cut it every year. 
Just to be clear, i am not even sure if there are wasps there yet. Am I worrying over nothing?

[image: Tree]

Comment: what country are you in? I can give you a definite answer for the UK, but you may live somewhere that has other kinds of wasps with other habits

Comment: Wasps are pollinators, yes?  I would just pick/harvest the fruit before it has a chance to fall and rot.  You want wasps and bees to visit.  Otherwise, wasps might enjoy the rotting fruit.  I can't imagine controlling who visits your trees.  Keeping the fruit from hanging on the tree too long or rotting on the ground would take care of the wasps later in the year.  They also LOVE barbeques and the meat especially.  Are you allergic to stings?